# I'm trying to access DIC from API that loaded in console in Swift

Tags: ios, swift3

Here is my code:

```
unc downloadJsonWithURL() {
   let prodURL = "my api "
   let prams = ["gender":"Men"]
    Alamofire.request(prodURL, method: .post, parameters: prams, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            let json = response.result.value as!NSDictionary
            //self.nameArray =  (json as? [String]!)!

                //self.productsArr = json as! NSArray
               // self.nameArray.append("name")
                print("Products loaded\(String(describing: json.value(forKey:"0")))")



        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error!)
            break

        }
    }
```

When I run it, in the console I get nil, but when I change it to 0 that get it from api, it show my data like that in console:

```
   Products loadedOptional(<__NSArrayI 0x6180001c9c90>(
{
    "accessory_id" = 6;
    "arabic_name" = "\U0633\U0628\U062d\U0629 \U062c\U0645\U0634\U062a";
    "category_id" = 16;
    id = 41;
    "main_image" = ""
    name = "Prophet Velen Rosry";
},
```

I want to access it and take { id , name , main_image } and press it into table view cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you need this or something like this

```
if let json = json as? [Any], let myDict = json["0"] as? [String:Any] {
    //Use myDict as your output dict
}
```

Comment: I tried it before 
tab any? has no subscript members

Comment: I tried it and I tried many solutions my problem is I can't access json that comes from api all I want to do is get those value 
the id and name and image 
my data loaded in console and I don't know how print it in table view

Comment: What is the datatype of response, it is Data or Any and where your code fails, exactly on which line?

Comment: my datatype nsarray  >> where in my code fails nothing >> like you see my json in 2nd code like that I don't how to make it object I hope you understand me and I'm sorry if my English not good thank you for trying helping me <3

Comment: try this `if let json = json as? [Any], let myDict = json["0"] as? [String:Any] { }` or share your response if you can.. i assume the second code is your first object of array.

Comment: yes I figure it yes that was missed thank you  a lot @Amit Battan